# THREE.js Blender exporter doesn't export exactly same amount of vertices

Tags: three.js

I am new to Three.js, first I want to thank everyone who worked on THREE.js. It is  easy to use, and powerful. 
Recently I exported a t shirt from Blender using Three.js exporter. After I import t shirt into webgl using JSONLoader, the number of vertices of the shirt in Blender and webgl is not same. The one in Blender only has 81 vertices but the one in webgl has 1480 vertices. And the color didn't show up correctly. 
Things I have checked when export from Blender.
Geometry: vertices, faces, normals , bones, skinning
Materials: UVs, Colors, Materials 
Settings:Flip YZ,  scale:0.05
Scene: Embed meshes
Settings: All meshes

Wondering why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you also export "bones" ans "skinning" , doesn't it mean that you are trying to export some animated model? If so it might be related to it. But how did you get to know the number of vertices in three.js? Have you for example tried to enable wireframing to see if your imported shirt has the whole 1480 vertices?

Comment: I have those checked because it is default. I acutely don't know what are "bones" and "skinning". We can tell how many vertices of a mesh in the geometry object when debugging.

Comment: Bones and skinning are tools to create animation, they don't haveto be checed if you aren't creating an animation